# Are shields subject to armor/magic resist damage reductions?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was playing Shen the other night and thoroughly enjoying it, but it seemed like a few times I cast my ultimate, the shield was just ripped apart in no time flat.  I was usually using it on carries who weren't building much defense, but the ~900-1000 damage shield was disappearing so fast, with only a couple people attacking my ally it seems like it doesn't get any benefit from the damage reductions.

Is that right or am I just misjudging it?  Same question for Lux, Morgana, Malphite, and other characters with damage shields.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shields act as health - which means that they have the same damage resistances as the character they were used on. This means that, for instance, a 1000 hitpoint shield will only give 1000 points of absorbed damage on a champion with 0 armor and MR. Usually, it's a fair bit more than this.

The thing is, in League of Legends, it's much easier to increase offense than defense. Carries are focus targets to begin with, so even a 1000 point shield goes down fast under 3-4 different champions attacking it. Most endgame carries can crit each other for over 600, easily.

Ultimately, shields might go down fast, but you *are* effectively giving them temporary health, not a simple damage reduction.

Comment: To build on this, riot added the silver life-bars when the shield is active. If you have the shield on and your health is at 100% you get a boost of lets say 1000 health at your Armor and MR. It is very noticeable on Blitz's ult.

Answer (score 0):

I am 100% certain that armor & mr apply to [Shields](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Shield).

> Shield refers to the game mechanic which grants temporary health to a champion for some time.
>   All shields take the champion's resistances into account when receiving damage to the temporary health.

Comment: I'm not sure why you felt the need to chime in 5 years after the question was answered.